# Unable to add a K8s service as prometheus target

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, servicemonitor

I want my prometheus server to scrape metrics from a pod.

I followed these steps:

1. Created a pod using deployment - `kubectl apply -f sample-app.deploy.yaml`
2. Exposed the same using `kubectl apply -f sample-app.service.yaml`
3. Deployed Prometheus server using `helm upgrade -i prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus -f prometheus-values.yaml`
4. created a serviceMonitor using `kubectl apply -f service-monitor.yaml` to add a target for prometheus.

All pods are running, but when I open prometheus dashboard, **I don't see *sample-app service* as prometheus target, under status>targets in dashboard UI.**

I've verified following:

1. I can see `sample-app` when I execute `kubectl get servicemonitors`
2. I can see sample-app exposes metrics in prometheus format under at `/metrics`

At this point I debugged further, entered into the prometheus pod using
`kubectl exec -it pod/prometheus-server-65b759cb95-dxmkm -c prometheus-server sh`
, and saw that proemetheus configuration (/etc/config/prometheus.yml) didn't have sample-app as one of the jobs so I edited the configmap using

`kubectl edit cm prometheus-server -o yaml`
Added

```
    - job_name: sample-app
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - sample-app:8080
```

Assuming all other fields such as **scraping** interval, scrape_timeout stays default.

I can see the same has been reflected in /etc/config/prometheus.yml, but still prometheus dashboard doesn't show `sample-app` as targets under status>targets.

following are yamls for prometheus-server and service monitor.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment: '{"input":{"containers":[{"name":"prometheus-server-configmap-reload"},{"name":"prometheus-server"}]},"output":{"containers":[{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"name":"prometheus-server-configmap-reload"},{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"name":"prometheus-server"}]},"modified":true}'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: prom
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-24T10:42:31Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: prometheus-14.2.1
    component: server
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-server
  namespace: prom
  resourceVersion: "6983855"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/prom/deployments/prometheus-server
  uid: <some-uid>
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
      component: server
      release: prometheus
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: prometheus
        chart: prometheus-14.2.1
        component: server
        heritage: Helm
        release: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --volume-dir=/etc/config
        - --webhook-url=http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload
        image: jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.5.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: prometheus-server-configmap-reload
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 2Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - NET_RAW
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/config
          name: config-volume
          readOnly: true
      - args:
        - --storage.tsdb.retention.time=15d
        - --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
        - --storage.tsdb.path=/data
        - --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
        - --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
        - --web.enable-lifecycle
        image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.26.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /-/healthy
            port: 9090
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 15
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        name: prometheus-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /-/ready
            port: 9090
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 4
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 2Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - NET_RAW
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/config
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /data
          name: storage-volume
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534
        runAsGroup: 65534
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
        seccompProfile:
          type: RuntimeDefault
      serviceAccount: prometheus-server
      serviceAccountName: prometheus-server
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: prometheus-server
        name: config-volume
      - name: storage-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: prometheus-server
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-06-24T10:43:25Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-06-24T10:43:25Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-06-24T10:42:31Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-06-24T10:43:25Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "prometheus-server-65b759cb95" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

yaml for service Monitor

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"monitoring.coreos.com/v1","kind":"ServiceMonitor","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2021-06-24T07:55:58Z","generation":1,"labels":{"app":"sample-app","release":"prometheus"},"name":"sample-app","namespace":"prom","resourceVersion":"6884573","selfLink":"/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/prom/servicemonitors/sample-app","uid":"34644b62-eb4f-4ab1-b9df-b22811e40b4c"},"spec":{"endpoints":[{"port":"http"}],"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"sample-app","release":"prometheus"}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-24T07:55:58Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: sample-app
    release: prometheus
  name: sample-app
  namespace: prom
  resourceVersion: "6904642"
  selfLink: /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/prom/servicemonitors/sample-app
  uid: <some-uid>
spec:
  endpoints:
  - port: http
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-app
      release: prometheus
```

Comment: Did you tried port-forwarding your sample-app and get the /metrics endpoint that needs to be scraped by prometheus? Is your /metrics endpoint available and working?

Comment: Yes. pod is sending metrics to /metrics endpoint in prometheus format. Verified using port-forwarding

Comment: does your service has an endpoint? try kubectl get endpoints and check the output

Comment: @meaningqo Yes service has endpoint. I'm able to  `curl --request GET   --url 'http://my_endpoint_ip:8080/metrics'`

Comment: if you are running the prometheus operator service monitor, you don't need to edit config map manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` chart, which includes the Prometheus operator, in order to have Prometheus' configuration update automatically based on ServiceMonitor resources.

The `prometheus-community/prometheus` chart you used does not include the Prometheus operator that watches for ServiceMonitor resources in the Kubernetes API and updates the Prometheus server's ConfigMap accordingly.

It seems that you have the necessary CustomResourceDefinitions (CRDs) installed in your cluster, otherwise you would not have been able to create a ServiceMonitor resource. These are not included in the `prometheus-community/prometheus` chart so perhaps they were added to your cluster previously.

Comment: I'm running these workloads on GKE autopilot cluster, it gave me "mutatingwebhookconfigurations access denied" error while deploying `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`. Looks like that's the [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#webhooks_limitations) of GKE auto pilot. Let me try out on standard-cluster.

Comment: I tried the suggestion provided by you on a standard-cluster, it works.